# Replace apt-get nginx with nginx from source

Tags: nginx

I have nginx installed on ubuntu from apt-get and I'm trying to re-install from source with specific modules.  I'm doing standard install from source `./configure ...` `make` `make install` all goes well, however it's not actually replacing the current nginx instance.   Any idea how to replace current install?

Comment: Why not remove old one? Do `nginx -s stop` and then `apt-get remove nginx`

Comment: @TarunLalwani You're right, I was under the impression the new install would override the old, not the case.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx compiled from source will not overwrite the system nginx. You need to remove the system package

```
apt-get remove nginx
```

And then use `make install` in the compiled source